# Xpadder not working with MotionInJoy + DualShock 3

Tags: pc, motioninjoy-ds3tool

I wanted to play GTA: San Andreas with my DualShock 3. Unfortunately you can't set the same button for 2 different things (like it is on the PS2). So I installed MotionInJoy and Xpadder, but Xpadder does not recognize any button at all. In MotionInJoy the Custom LED's and the Vibration test works fine, and this controller works perfect on my PS3. I am sure I clicked 'enable' in MotionInJoy.

Comment: How are you using a Playstation controller on your PC?

Comment: Do the buttons work fine if you set it to say Xbox360? E.g. the controller is working fine but the Xpadder stuff isn't?

Comment: @BenBrocka USB Cable

Comment: Do you have the buttons in MotionInJoy mapped to 'Gamepad' buttons or keyboard buttons?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you haven't got the driver installed.

Check Game controllers in Windows Control panel see if the pad is recognized.  In the MotioninJoy app go to the drivers page and install the driver with your pad plugged in.

I'd also recommend trying [Better DS3](http://betterds3.ciebiera.net/) Instead of Xpadder. 
EDIT only if you have to use the chinese Driver, otherwise use [XInput Wrapper for DS3](http://forums.pcsx2.net/Thread-XInput-Wrapper-for-DS3-and-Play-com-USB-Dual-DS2-Controller) as its much cleaner

Comment: +1, MotionInJoy is just about the worst driver for the DS3 controller there is. I've had nothing but problems with it, and it's probably the closest thing to malware I've ever installed on purpose.

Comment: I agree, it is a nefarious seeming app. I now use SCP Service, runs as a service in Windows and emulates the Xbox Controller perfectly.